# Create a subprocess in python and exit after some timeout

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am new in python, so I am not able to create the python script in following scenario:

```
1. Run a sub process.
2. Need to check in every 5 sec a file stop.txt is exit then
3. Stop the subrocess and exit from the script.
4. If not exit the stop.txt. then need to continue the sub process.
```

Thanks in adv.

Comment: The best way would be to handle that in a subprocess. Otherwise you will have to call `.kill` from parent.

Comment: @freakish: I have only one  sub process p = subprocess.Popen(), How to kill after some interval.

Answer (score 0):

For a process to be run as in through the terminal, look at the [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module. To wait 5 seconds, use the [time](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html) module. After the wait you can open the file in read mode, then read until you find 'exit'. A quick example:

```
import subproccess, time
background_task = subproccess.Popen(background_task)
while 1:
    time.sleep(5)
    with open('background_task.txt', 'r') as task_file:
        if task_file.read() == 'exit':
            background_task.kill() 
            exit()
```